# How to delete content after certain time period

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I am trying to create a content type for alerts on a website. Each alert should have an expiration date. Is there a way to programmatically delete these alerts in Contentful after the expiration date has passed?

Comment: I'm not sure about deleting it from the contentful side, but you could probably conditionally create it on the gatsby side. For example, only create it if it were less than 6 months old.

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested example how you could implement it conditionally in Gatsby:

```
function AlertTemplate(props) {
  const { data: { blog: { html, frontmatter } } } = props;

  let youngerThan6Months = false;
  const SIX_MONTHS = 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
  // 6months * 30days in month * 24hours in day * 60minutes in hour * 60seconds in minute * 1000millisconds in second

  if (((new Date) - frontmatter.date) < SIX_MONTHS) {
    youngerThan6Months = true;
  }

  if (youngerThan6Months) {
    return (
      <YourAlertWrapper>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
      </YourAlertWrapper>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```